# Sort NSMutableArray by date and then by alphabetical order

Tags: objective-c, sorting

I have an NSMutable array of objects. The objects represent football (soccer) matches and have an `NSString` parameter called `title` (ed "Arsenal v Chelsea"), and an `NSDate` parameter called `ActualDate`.

I am sorting the array by date at the moment using the following code:

```
NSMutableArray* a = [self getMatchListFromURL:@"http://www.url.com"];
[a sortUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"ActualDate" ascending:YES]]];
```

Obviously there are multiple games that happen on the same date. I would like to sort games that happen on the same date in alphabetical order. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method `sortUsingDescriptors` takes array of `NSSortDescriptor` as an argument. So you can pass multiple sort descriptors to method as follow:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortAlphabetical = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *sortByDate = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"ActualDate" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortAlphabetical, sortByDate];
//perform sorting
[a sortUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to implement this, but I think the most readable is to implement a comparison block, like so:

```
[a sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(SomeClass *obj1, SomeClass *obj2) {
    NSComparisonResult dateCompare = [obj1.actualDate compare:obj2.actualDate];

    if (dateCompare != NSOrderedSame) {
        return dateCompare;
    } else {
        return [obj1.title compare:obj2.title];
    }
}];
```

This will sort `a` first by its `actualDate` property, and if they're the same, then by the `title`property. You can add additional logic if you need to.

You could, alternatively, add additional `NSSortDescriptor` objects to the array you pass to `sortUsingDescriptors:`, but I think that's less readable.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise that you could set up these custom comparators. This could be useful for another portion of the app I'm working on.

Comment: They would be quite obvious if you opened the NSArray header file or read the documentation. Don't you do that?